# Python-docx style format

Tags: python, pandas, python-docx

I am using python-docx to output a Pandas DataFrame to a Word table.  About a year ago, I wrote this code to build that table, which worked at the time:

```
table = Rpt.add_table(rows=1, cols=(df.shape[1]+1))
table.style = 'LightShading-Accent2'
```

Where `Rpt` is a Document from a template.  Now, I get an error:

```
KeyError: "no style with name 'LightShading-Accent2'"
```

How should I go about defining the style?  Has the naming convention changed in newer versions of python-docx?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, slightly, apologies for that, but it was the right long-term decision for the API.

Try using "Light Shading - Accent 2" instead. It should be the name just as it appears in the Word user interface (UI).

If you still can't get it, you can enumerate all the style names with something like this:

```
from docx import Document

document = Document()
styles = document.styles
for style in styles:
    print "'%s' -- %s" % (style.name, style.type)
```

If you want to narrow it down a bit, say to only table styles, you can add this:

```
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE

styles = [s for s in document.styles if s.type == WD_STYLE_TYPE.TABLE]
for style in styles:
    print(style.name)
```

The printed names will give you the exact spellings.

Comment: I still get the same error:  KeyError: "no style with name 'Light Shading - Accent 2'".  Using version 0.8.5 on Python 3.5.1

Comment: Did you find that style in the list when you enumerated the style names as I mentioned?

Comment: I didn't -- the second snippet only had two styles, 'Normal Table' and 'Table Grid'.  I checked the template, and all the usual Word default tables were available

Comment: Ah, well, that would explain it then :) `python-docx` does not automatically add styles that are not present; it has no way of knowing just what attributes they would have, for one thing. I suggest reading this page and the one following it in the documentation: http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-understanding.html. The short version is you have to get the style into your "starting" document before you can use it. If you still have questions you can start another question. I'll see it if it's tagged with 'python-docx'.

Comment: If you start your document using the default built-in template, that style is present. I do notice though that the name doesn't have the hyphen, so it's just 'Light Shading Accent 2'. I've changed the code above to show that.

Comment: That's it.  I was using a custom template, expecting it to work like the default built-in one.

Comment: Thank you for a very useful, long-overdue library.  I use it all the time

Comment: The Word application shows a set of "built-in/preset" styles as available at all times, whether they're present in the document or not. If you pick one that's not in the document, it adds it into the document. So an easy way to get it into a custom document/template is to assign it to some item (table in this case), then delete that item. The item is removed, but styles stay forever once added.